# How to invoke apply on multiple columns (including the result column) without looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numba

For example, I have two columns A and B (as in pandas dataframe):

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  0  0
```

How do I calculate a column C based on A, B, and C_prev_row (its own calculated value from previous row), to get the below result:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  1
3  0  0  0
```

The formula I wish to apply is:

```
C = A * C_prev_row + B, the initial C_prev_row = 0.
```

for row 0:

```
C0 = 1 * 0 + 1 = 1
```

for row 1:

```
C1 = 1 * 1 + 0 = 1
```

for row 2:

```
C2 = 0 * 1 + 1 = 1
```

for row 3:

```
C3 = 0 * 1 + 0 = 0
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through the rows for better performance?

Comment: Is it a pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes, it is.....

Comment: with previous you mean, the previous row or the previous column value?

Comment: Previous row value

Comment: Are you able to use Numba?  It will be absolutely trivial then.

Comment: Haven't use it before, but yeah, Numba will do as well, as long as it can convert the result into dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You need break down you logic behind the value C

```
(df.A.iloc[1:].cumprod()*1).add((df.A.iloc[2:].cumprod()*df.B.iloc[1])+df.B,fill_value=0).fillna(1)
Out[983]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
dtype: float64
```

More Info

```
C1=1

C2=A2*C1+B2

C3=A3*C2+B3=A3*A2*C1+A3*B2+B3

C4=A4*C3+B4=A4*A3*A2*C1+A4*A3*B2+B4
```

Comment: Will this approach scale say to n rows?

Comment: @liang i think it is .

Comment: so how to calculate Cn?